# how to plot the distribution of the data without histogram

Tags: matlab, histogram, distribution

I have data and I want to show the distribution of them in Matlab. Could you help me with how to plot it? I don't want to fit a normal distribution. In the following, I have the histogram and a normal which fit them.

```
data = [1243.66361214496    1243.52480651719    1243.65867190219    1243.50894451745    1243.66201545850    1243.51116213754    1243.50965898634    1243.51057677366    1243.51242552229    1243.50907384203    1243.52631256666    1243.52607543501    1243.00404027600    1243.00369742316    1243.00355228980    1243.00335204530    1243.00311985389    1243.00324950781    1243.00315333775    1243.00358313887    1243.00377624747    1243.00374473970    1243.00354021365    1243.00385024133    1243.00405542608    1243.00212044058    1243.00360697939    1243.71251571790    1243.25308937922    1243.25312521245    1243.25310045634    1243.25304011951    1243.25325794601    1243.25303969136    1243.25307359240    1243.25305166870    1243.25325374132    1243.25322405595    1243.25320683097    1243.25322773368    1243.25324186278    1243.25303293969    1243.25303986701    1243.25304490606    1243.25305894733    1243.25307537089    1243.25309133336    1243.25310870106    1243.25310356321    1243.25308940118    1243.25308880835    1243.25308941216    1243.25308292397    1243.25307002445    1243.25305111979    1243.25303469622    1243.25303231393    1243.25303370817    1243.25325823145    1243.25325363153    1243.25306793857    1243.25306418398    1243.25304784825    1243.25305293121    1243.25306341550    1243.25309481349    1243.25316685321    1243.25314655430    1243.25309024651    1243.28026133845    1243.27894503821    1243.28290381941    1243.28113850600    1243.28143821406    1243.27830610014    1243.29804239196    1243.28006812007    1243.27946650828    1243.27726974700    1243.27728072531    1243.28316949469    1243.28364266017    1243.28297078715    1243.28266998126    1243.27881659190    1243.28134050704    1243.28550348494    1243.28356471411    1243.28187405325    1243.28273804682    1243.28144370322    1243.27771436884    1243.27953018252    1243.28072901476    1243.27659128699    1243.27696345194    1243.29757800914    1243.29629683951    1243.29708288703    1243.29783709742    1243.29687210334    1243.29490808238    1243.29356543418    1243.29154761947    1243.29338648761    1243.29717290923    1243.27758153121    1243.27860031905    1243.27768582522    1243.28075646056    1243.28593054148    1243.28297517848    1243.28113301684    1243.28145029021    1243.28234172957    1243.28415095625    1243.28424207629    1243.28248554553    1243.28002969596    1243.27874852633    1243.29849140513    1243.29337770495    1243.27640355776    1243.27981561877    1243.27897907099    1243.29881087417    1243.29164752215    1243.28596185164    1243.29393101214    1243.27773961897    1243.29585770682    1243.27721814890    1243.29592796805    1243.27940942103    1243.27942479067    1243.29387282706    1243.29321412803    1247.56159191513    1247.38473122406    1247.04209794235    1246.41106426621    1245.65290167618    1244.87914987564    1244.87047700501    1244.76629277420    1245.03284631729    1245.53883695984    1247.49023285294    1243.29029609130    1243.28107759829    1245.05557143402    1243.20995856603    1243.27324162674    1243.21427137601    1243.27776315649    1245.08071178055    1243.28612902946    1245.11979459000    1243.29815028686    1243.27802703132    1243.56634601056    1243.28581065826    1246.29249843979    1244.72347733688    1247.34246470261    1243.27985900508    1243.28423825583    1243.28552820811    1247.73812325668    1246.92473973084    1246.02210248566    1245.31158579254    1243.20771073361    1243.28957622108    1243.65076927029    1243.60564838635    1243.65230623471    1243.27830148925    1243.28261596794    1243.28023367309    1243.27866377372    1243.27860888214    1243.29780995902    1245.07050194550    1246.42489694595    1244.78956680679    1247.41470203018    1243.28413286399    1243.28732865214    1243.28903029132    1243.28001928851    1247.54424617386    1247.01860434341    1246.40392835999    1245.55607291794    1244.82436807251    1243.29167141097    1243.28971893920    1243.28699631652    1243.29654745254    1243.28181288207    1243.27905732444    1243.28645837898    1243.71257719647    1243.69709776913    1243.70094018018    1243.27603995590    1243.28148520126    1243.29228786544    1243.28135179275    1243.29002633209    1243.27853203391    1243.27966280059    1243.28181455078    1243.28257205467    1243.28102411193    1243.28110096015    1243.28604120292    1243.29498853149    1243.29017835982    1243.63117780444    1244.75454597473    1244.87475854874    1244.85444866180    1243.66586928699    1243.28855356887    1243.29290265121    1243.28642544402    1243.28151813621    1243.27933345107    1243.27788431320    1243.27827953262    1243.28197922553    1243.28817099647    1243.29270504150    1243.29273797645    1243.28575576667    1243.28462499999    1243.27844420738    1243.27697311286    1243.69094991147    1243.21467713461    1243.20754122839    1243.22927829657    1243.21895867834    1243.69918364941    1243.27681941642    1243.27802703132    1243.27966280059    1243.28274770774    1243.28114487342    1243.28462499999    1243.28170476760    1243.28407608413    1243.28195726890    1243.28799534339    1243.28328564529    1243.28144128799    1243.27923464622    1243.27852105560    1243.70873478543    1243.27647908859    1243.70774673688    1243.69742711865    1243.27587528114    1243.27599604263    1243.69764668500    1243.63309417950    1243.61794410168    1243.57359169995    1243.57051777112    1243.60334293973    1243.58885156094    1243.59049830853    1243.63759528958    1243.66515086591    1243.69040099561    1243.69995213162    1243.21083472357    1243.21895867834    1243.21588474951    1243.21160320578    1243.21654344855    1243.64319423138    1243.63792463910    1243.22016629324    1243.27645713195    1243.28242933654    1243.29187068939    1243.29868822441    1243.27915612929    1243.29016738151    1243.51129457996    1243.56245353839    1243.56871117923    1243.21026771544    1243.48615423343    1243.29500881942    1243.29303272231    1243.29012346824    1243.28853161223    1243.29036499122    1243.29343892005    1243.29868655570    1243.22179494857    1243.63370281741    1243.22121406384    1243.71296626804    1244.66090092850    1244.67857601929    1244.67725862122    1244.64289648819    1243.20913791486    1243.58133624408    1243.55323175189    1243.51766200397    1243.29873046897    1243.29381218284    1243.29435012038    1243.29313152717    1243.29234108832    1243.28820226272    1243.28710443099    1243.28666529830    1243.28826813262    1243.28830106757    1243.28496365912    1243.28538083518    1243.28416224196    1243.28444767821    1243.28024298270    1243.27920004256    1243.27834373382    1243.27709220565    1243.29868822441    1243.29801854705    1243.27743253348    1243.27629078849    1243.29598755836    1243.29514222793    1243.29403341789    1243.29643766937    1243.27646644157    1243.29456037712    1243.27626883185    1243.28295462707    1243.28454648307    1243.28358039115    1243.29635915244    1243.48450748584    1243.52018701694    1243.55861112735    1243.55246326968    1243.22783302306    1243.22212429808    1243.21180467986    1243.29862068580    1243.29539306052    1243.29299978736    1243.29185804236    1243.29549186538    1243.29529425567    1243.49219230792    1243.51875983569    1243.59275369403    1243.65522031924    1244.66792705154    1244.79560488129    1244.89210429001    1245.01012120056    1245.07675958633    1245.18566449356    1245.18193186569    1245.06654975128    1244.90692501831    1244.74488505554    1243.64896267841    1243.49131404254    1243.28588583777    1243.28053939727    1243.28633594878    1243.29122129996    1243.29237402328    1243.29283511260    1243.50174344394    1243.59560805652    1243.22845975323    1244.64256713867    1243.21901840039    1243.22824018689    1244.67385534287    1244.67923471832    1244.65859548187    1243.70626949451    1243.64281482074    1243.44335407793    1243.29590904143    1243.28990390189    1243.28401952384    1243.27788264449    1243.29539472923    1243.29599853668    1243.29845767974    1243.27752036002    1243.28191168693    1243.29115543006    1243.43742578661    1243.57211445758    1243.60153634784    1243.65697685001    1244.63740732956    1244.71985449219    1244.77683195877    1244.73555348587    1243.45506890854    1243.59813306949    1243.55487849948    1243.29665556701    1243.28843280738    1243.28271310409    1243.29763430595    1243.29460429038    1243.29762332763    1243.29456037712    1243.29626201629    1243.27813514579    1243.28554550994    1243.28908052810    1243.29462457831    1243.49504667041    1243.60318309543    1244.64673889923    1244.76014491653    1244.88946949387    1245.00024071503    1245.07478348923    1245.04514203262    1244.93766430664    1244.82118436050    1243.44683517059    1243.43863340151    1243.28192266524    1243.28365890807    1243.65109861981    1243.61366255795    1243.65142796933    1243.63034960019    1243.65790517651    1243.27776355171    1243.29145351333    1243.27945254386    1243.28426104682    1243.28850965560    1243.29623839095    1243.52271202991    1243.60779398868    1243.64094850681    1243.57222424075    1243.28572116302    1243.29243058357    1243.28000312843    1243.66580956494    1243.57743411099    1243.50805114590    1243.69579705811    1243.43833883130    1243.70864168930    1243.52715341794    1243.61333320844    1243.60938101422    1243.60015922772    1243.61772453534    1243.43931019281    1243.70994240033    1243.27700604782    1243.27987138862    1243.28497630615    1243.28349423332    1243.71169893109    1243.65274536740    1243.62881263577    1243.61014949643    1243.56755362546    1243.57622649609    1243.58248413693    1243.57875150906    1243.45580963756    1243.52243274152    1243.43923237850    1243.44527045299    1243.44570958568    1243.55218398129    1243.62947133481    1243.44062759088    1243.62354304349    1243.58259392011    1243.56382099759    1243.59313310468    1243.61223537671    1243.61212559354    1243.63781485593    1243.44633631586    1243.70170866238    1243.45753419946    1243.22750147788    1243.22803941542    1243.22896159407    1243.27790626983    1243.27779648666    1243.22870909278    1243.22338460891    1243.21919089171    1243.45591942073    1243.21052899939    1243.20900301329    1243.20935431945    1243.20989225699    1243.22932554725    1243.20942018935    1243.21829066970    1243.22390058982    1243.22324189078    1243.22065100791    1243.63891268765    1243.63957138669    1243.60883209836    1243.61607778775    1243.64264531552    1243.69160861050    1243.27821366271    1243.28192433395    1243.28579967994    1243.28958719940    1243.28854425926    1243.28006899833    1243.70445324170    1243.64978122174    1243.61640713727    1243.59412115323    1243.62727567136    1243.70851521909    1243.28374673461    1243.29154133987    1243.29284775962    1243.29382482986    1243.29290265121    1243.29543864250    1243.29819420013    1243.29729397811    1243.29311123924    1243.29471407356    1243.29479092178    1243.28534956893    1243.27741224555    1243.69062056195    1243.27859790382    1243.28474576148    1243.28898339195    1243.29674506225    1243.27854134353    1243.28180190375    1243.29488805793    1243.56508833453    1243.65642793414    1243.45312478029    1243.28953063911    1243.27693850921    1243.29196949424    1243.29302341270    1243.29569114379    1243.27623589690    1243.29658038749    1243.29619614639    1243.29082774925    1243.29245254020    1243.29156329650    1243.28953230781    1243.28514098091    1243.28393336601    1243.28774284210    1243.28813806152    1243.28845643272    1243.28720490455    1243.28833567123    1243.29101438064    1243.27728981536    1243.29251674140    1243.61108748386    1244.63641928101];
disdata = histfit(data)
```

Comment: How many bins or bin size did you wish to have? Curious what's the reason against using the `histogram()` function?

Comment: I used different numbers of bins. I don't know. My supervisor told me to change the histogram to the PDF.

Comment: So you essentially want to divide the histogram results by the number of data points to give you the probability. Then change it to a line graph?

Comment: Do you want something on the lines of this but with probability on the y-axis? https://github.com/MichaelTr7/StackOverflow/tree/master/Histogram

Comment: Exactly. I want something like the figure that you sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Method 1: Using `hist()` Built-In Function

Using the function `hist()` returns the counts/occurrences and the corresponding centres of the bins for the dataset. The number of bins can be changed according to your preference using either method.
[image: Probability Graph Using hist() Function]

```
Data = [1243.66361214496    1243.52480651719    1243.65867190219    1243.50894451745    1243.66201545850    1243.51116213754    1243.50965898634    1243.51057677366    1243.51242552229    1243.50907384203    1243.52631256666    1243.52607543501    1243.00404027600    1243.00369742316    1243.00355228980    1243.00335204530    1243.00311985389    1243.00324950781    1243.00315333775    1243.00358313887    1243.00377624747    1243.00374473970    1243.00354021365    1243.00385024133    1243.00405542608    1243.00212044058    1243.00360697939    1243.71251571790    1243.25308937922    1243.25312521245    1243.25310045634    1243.25304011951    1243.25325794601    1243.25303969136    1243.25307359240    1243.25305166870    1243.25325374132    1243.25322405595    1243.25320683097    1243.25322773368    1243.25324186278    1243.25303293969    1243.25303986701    1243.25304490606    1243.25305894733    1243.25307537089    1243.25309133336    1243.25310870106    1243.25310356321    1243.25308940118    1243.25308880835    1243.25308941216    1243.25308292397    1243.25307002445    1243.25305111979    1243.25303469622    1243.25303231393    1243.25303370817    1243.25325823145    1243.25325363153    1243.25306793857    1243.25306418398    1243.25304784825    1243.25305293121    1243.25306341550    1243.25309481349    1243.25316685321    1243.25314655430    1243.25309024651    1243.28026133845    1243.27894503821    1243.28290381941    1243.28113850600    1243.28143821406    1243.27830610014    1243.29804239196    1243.28006812007    1243.27946650828    1243.27726974700    1243.27728072531    1243.28316949469    1243.28364266017    1243.28297078715    1243.28266998126    1243.27881659190    1243.28134050704    1243.28550348494    1243.28356471411    1243.28187405325    1243.28273804682    1243.28144370322    1243.27771436884    1243.27953018252    1243.28072901476    1243.27659128699    1243.27696345194    1243.29757800914    1243.29629683951    1243.29708288703    1243.29783709742    1243.29687210334    1243.29490808238    1243.29356543418    1243.29154761947    1243.29338648761    1243.29717290923    1243.27758153121    1243.27860031905    1243.27768582522    1243.28075646056    1243.28593054148    1243.28297517848    1243.28113301684    1243.28145029021    1243.28234172957    1243.28415095625    1243.28424207629    1243.28248554553    1243.28002969596    1243.27874852633    1243.29849140513    1243.29337770495    1243.27640355776    1243.27981561877    1243.27897907099    1243.29881087417    1243.29164752215    1243.28596185164    1243.29393101214    1243.27773961897    1243.29585770682    1243.27721814890    1243.29592796805    1243.27940942103    1243.27942479067    1243.29387282706    1243.29321412803    1247.56159191513    1247.38473122406    1247.04209794235    1246.41106426621    1245.65290167618    1244.87914987564    1244.87047700501    1244.76629277420    1245.03284631729    1245.53883695984    1247.49023285294    1243.29029609130    1243.28107759829    1245.05557143402    1243.20995856603    1243.27324162674    1243.21427137601    1243.27776315649    1245.08071178055    1243.28612902946    1245.11979459000    1243.29815028686    1243.27802703132    1243.56634601056    1243.28581065826    1246.29249843979    1244.72347733688    1247.34246470261    1243.27985900508    1243.28423825583    1243.28552820811    1247.73812325668    1246.92473973084    1246.02210248566    1245.31158579254    1243.20771073361    1243.28957622108    1243.65076927029    1243.60564838635    1243.65230623471    1243.27830148925    1243.28261596794    1243.28023367309    1243.27866377372    1243.27860888214    1243.29780995902    1245.07050194550    1246.42489694595    1244.78956680679    1247.41470203018    1243.28413286399    1243.28732865214    1243.28903029132    1243.28001928851    1247.54424617386    1247.01860434341    1246.40392835999    1245.55607291794    1244.82436807251    1243.29167141097    1243.28971893920    1243.28699631652    1243.29654745254    1243.28181288207    1243.27905732444    1243.28645837898    1243.71257719647    1243.69709776913    1243.70094018018    1243.27603995590    1243.28148520126    1243.29228786544    1243.28135179275    1243.29002633209    1243.27853203391    1243.27966280059    1243.28181455078    1243.28257205467    1243.28102411193    1243.28110096015    1243.28604120292    1243.29498853149    1243.29017835982    1243.63117780444    1244.75454597473    1244.87475854874    1244.85444866180    1243.66586928699    1243.28855356887    1243.29290265121    1243.28642544402    1243.28151813621    1243.27933345107    1243.27788431320    1243.27827953262    1243.28197922553    1243.28817099647    1243.29270504150    1243.29273797645    1243.28575576667    1243.28462499999    1243.27844420738    1243.27697311286    1243.69094991147    1243.21467713461    1243.20754122839    1243.22927829657    1243.21895867834    1243.69918364941    1243.27681941642    1243.27802703132    1243.27966280059    1243.28274770774    1243.28114487342    1243.28462499999    1243.28170476760    1243.28407608413    1243.28195726890    1243.28799534339    1243.28328564529    1243.28144128799    1243.27923464622    1243.27852105560    1243.70873478543    1243.27647908859    1243.70774673688    1243.69742711865    1243.27587528114    1243.27599604263    1243.69764668500    1243.63309417950    1243.61794410168    1243.57359169995    1243.57051777112    1243.60334293973    1243.58885156094    1243.59049830853    1243.63759528958    1243.66515086591    1243.69040099561    1243.69995213162    1243.21083472357    1243.21895867834    1243.21588474951    1243.21160320578    1243.21654344855    1243.64319423138    1243.63792463910    1243.22016629324    1243.27645713195    1243.28242933654    1243.29187068939    1243.29868822441    1243.27915612929    1243.29016738151    1243.51129457996    1243.56245353839    1243.56871117923    1243.21026771544    1243.48615423343    1243.29500881942    1243.29303272231    1243.29012346824    1243.28853161223    1243.29036499122    1243.29343892005    1243.29868655570    1243.22179494857    1243.63370281741    1243.22121406384    1243.71296626804    1244.66090092850    1244.67857601929    1244.67725862122    1244.64289648819    1243.20913791486    1243.58133624408    1243.55323175189    1243.51766200397    1243.29873046897    1243.29381218284    1243.29435012038    1243.29313152717    1243.29234108832    1243.28820226272    1243.28710443099    1243.28666529830    1243.28826813262    1243.28830106757    1243.28496365912    1243.28538083518    1243.28416224196    1243.28444767821    1243.28024298270    1243.27920004256    1243.27834373382    1243.27709220565    1243.29868822441    1243.29801854705    1243.27743253348    1243.27629078849    1243.29598755836    1243.29514222793    1243.29403341789    1243.29643766937    1243.27646644157    1243.29456037712    1243.27626883185    1243.28295462707    1243.28454648307    1243.28358039115    1243.29635915244    1243.48450748584    1243.52018701694    1243.55861112735    1243.55246326968    1243.22783302306    1243.22212429808    1243.21180467986    1243.29862068580    1243.29539306052    1243.29299978736    1243.29185804236    1243.29549186538    1243.29529425567    1243.49219230792    1243.51875983569    1243.59275369403    1243.65522031924    1244.66792705154    1244.79560488129    1244.89210429001    1245.01012120056    1245.07675958633    1245.18566449356    1245.18193186569    1245.06654975128    1244.90692501831    1244.74488505554    1243.64896267841    1243.49131404254    1243.28588583777    1243.28053939727    1243.28633594878    1243.29122129996    1243.29237402328    1243.29283511260    1243.50174344394    1243.59560805652    1243.22845975323    1244.64256713867    1243.21901840039    1243.22824018689    1244.67385534287    1244.67923471832    1244.65859548187    1243.70626949451    1243.64281482074    1243.44335407793    1243.29590904143    1243.28990390189    1243.28401952384    1243.27788264449    1243.29539472923    1243.29599853668    1243.29845767974    1243.27752036002    1243.28191168693    1243.29115543006    1243.43742578661    1243.57211445758    1243.60153634784    1243.65697685001    1244.63740732956    1244.71985449219    1244.77683195877    1244.73555348587    1243.45506890854    1243.59813306949    1243.55487849948    1243.29665556701    1243.28843280738    1243.28271310409    1243.29763430595    1243.29460429038    1243.29762332763    1243.29456037712    1243.29626201629    1243.27813514579    1243.28554550994    1243.28908052810    1243.29462457831    1243.49504667041    1243.60318309543    1244.64673889923    1244.76014491653    1244.88946949387    1245.00024071503    1245.07478348923    1245.04514203262    1244.93766430664    1244.82118436050    1243.44683517059    1243.43863340151    1243.28192266524    1243.28365890807    1243.65109861981    1243.61366255795    1243.65142796933    1243.63034960019    1243.65790517651    1243.27776355171    1243.29145351333    1243.27945254386    1243.28426104682    1243.28850965560    1243.29623839095    1243.52271202991    1243.60779398868    1243.64094850681    1243.57222424075    1243.28572116302    1243.29243058357    1243.28000312843    1243.66580956494    1243.57743411099    1243.50805114590    1243.69579705811    1243.43833883130    1243.70864168930    1243.52715341794    1243.61333320844    1243.60938101422    1243.60015922772    1243.61772453534    1243.43931019281    1243.70994240033    1243.27700604782    1243.27987138862    1243.28497630615    1243.28349423332    1243.71169893109    1243.65274536740    1243.62881263577    1243.61014949643    1243.56755362546    1243.57622649609    1243.58248413693    1243.57875150906    1243.45580963756    1243.52243274152    1243.43923237850    1243.44527045299    1243.44570958568    1243.55218398129    1243.62947133481    1243.44062759088    1243.62354304349    1243.58259392011    1243.56382099759    1243.59313310468    1243.61223537671    1243.61212559354    1243.63781485593    1243.44633631586    1243.70170866238    1243.45753419946    1243.22750147788    1243.22803941542    1243.22896159407    1243.27790626983    1243.27779648666    1243.22870909278    1243.22338460891    1243.21919089171    1243.45591942073    1243.21052899939    1243.20900301329    1243.20935431945    1243.20989225699    1243.22932554725    1243.20942018935    1243.21829066970    1243.22390058982    1243.22324189078    1243.22065100791    1243.63891268765    1243.63957138669    1243.60883209836    1243.61607778775    1243.64264531552    1243.69160861050    1243.27821366271    1243.28192433395    1243.28579967994    1243.28958719940    1243.28854425926    1243.28006899833    1243.70445324170    1243.64978122174    1243.61640713727    1243.59412115323    1243.62727567136    1243.70851521909    1243.28374673461    1243.29154133987    1243.29284775962    1243.29382482986    1243.29290265121    1243.29543864250    1243.29819420013    1243.29729397811    1243.29311123924    1243.29471407356    1243.29479092178    1243.28534956893    1243.27741224555    1243.69062056195    1243.27859790382    1243.28474576148    1243.28898339195    1243.29674506225    1243.27854134353    1243.28180190375    1243.29488805793    1243.56508833453    1243.65642793414    1243.45312478029    1243.28953063911    1243.27693850921    1243.29196949424    1243.29302341270    1243.29569114379    1243.27623589690    1243.29658038749    1243.29619614639    1243.29082774925    1243.29245254020    1243.29156329650    1243.28953230781    1243.28514098091    1243.28393336601    1243.28774284210    1243.28813806152    1243.28845643272    1243.28720490455    1243.28833567123    1243.29101438064    1243.27728981536    1243.29251674140    1243.61108748386    1244.63641928101];

Number_Of_Bins = 70;
[Counts,Centres] = hist(Data,Number_Of_Bins);

Probabilities = Counts./length(Data);
plot(Centres,Probabilities);
title("Probability Graph");
xlabel("Data Value"); ylabel("Probabilities");
grid;

%Checking that probabilities add to 1%
sum(Probabilities)
```

### Method 2: Using Loops and Manually Incrementing Bins

Two nested loops can be used to generate the histogram data as well. The inner loop scans through the dataset and checks if it is in the corresponding bin. The outer for-loop controls which bin the data is being filtered for.
[image: Probability Graph Manually Evaluated]

```
%Manually finding histogram%
Data = [1243.66361214496    1243.52480651719    1243.65867190219    1243.50894451745    1243.66201545850    1243.51116213754    1243.50965898634    1243.51057677366    1243.51242552229    1243.50907384203    1243.52631256666    1243.52607543501    1243.00404027600    1243.00369742316    1243.00355228980    1243.00335204530    1243.00311985389    1243.00324950781    1243.00315333775    1243.00358313887    1243.00377624747    1243.00374473970    1243.00354021365    1243.00385024133    1243.00405542608    1243.00212044058    1243.00360697939    1243.71251571790    1243.25308937922    1243.25312521245    1243.25310045634    1243.25304011951    1243.25325794601    1243.25303969136    1243.25307359240    1243.25305166870    1243.25325374132    1243.25322405595    1243.25320683097    1243.25322773368    1243.25324186278    1243.25303293969    1243.25303986701    1243.25304490606    1243.25305894733    1243.25307537089    1243.25309133336    1243.25310870106    1243.25310356321    1243.25308940118    1243.25308880835    1243.25308941216    1243.25308292397    1243.25307002445    1243.25305111979    1243.25303469622    1243.25303231393    1243.25303370817    1243.25325823145    1243.25325363153    1243.25306793857    1243.25306418398    1243.25304784825    1243.25305293121    1243.25306341550    1243.25309481349    1243.25316685321    1243.25314655430    1243.25309024651    1243.28026133845    1243.27894503821    1243.28290381941    1243.28113850600    1243.28143821406    1243.27830610014    1243.29804239196    1243.28006812007    1243.27946650828    1243.27726974700    1243.27728072531    1243.28316949469    1243.28364266017    1243.28297078715    1243.28266998126    1243.27881659190    1243.28134050704    1243.28550348494    1243.28356471411    1243.28187405325    1243.28273804682    1243.28144370322    1243.27771436884    1243.27953018252    1243.28072901476    1243.27659128699    1243.27696345194    1243.29757800914    1243.29629683951    1243.29708288703    1243.29783709742    1243.29687210334    1243.29490808238    1243.29356543418    1243.29154761947    1243.29338648761    1243.29717290923    1243.27758153121    1243.27860031905    1243.27768582522    1243.28075646056    1243.28593054148    1243.28297517848    1243.28113301684    1243.28145029021    1243.28234172957    1243.28415095625    1243.28424207629    1243.28248554553    1243.28002969596    1243.27874852633    1243.29849140513    1243.29337770495    1243.27640355776    1243.27981561877    1243.27897907099    1243.29881087417    1243.29164752215    1243.28596185164    1243.29393101214    1243.27773961897    1243.29585770682    1243.27721814890    1243.29592796805    1243.27940942103    1243.27942479067    1243.29387282706    1243.29321412803    1247.56159191513    1247.38473122406    1247.04209794235    1246.41106426621    1245.65290167618    1244.87914987564    1244.87047700501    1244.76629277420    1245.03284631729    1245.53883695984    1247.49023285294    1243.29029609130    1243.28107759829    1245.05557143402    1243.20995856603    1243.27324162674    1243.21427137601    1243.27776315649    1245.08071178055    1243.28612902946    1245.11979459000    1243.29815028686    1243.27802703132    1243.56634601056    1243.28581065826    1246.29249843979    1244.72347733688    1247.34246470261    1243.27985900508    1243.28423825583    1243.28552820811    1247.73812325668    1246.92473973084    1246.02210248566    1245.31158579254    1243.20771073361    1243.28957622108    1243.65076927029    1243.60564838635    1243.65230623471    1243.27830148925    1243.28261596794    1243.28023367309    1243.27866377372    1243.27860888214    1243.29780995902    1245.07050194550    1246.42489694595    1244.78956680679    1247.41470203018    1243.28413286399    1243.28732865214    1243.28903029132    1243.28001928851    1247.54424617386    1247.01860434341    1246.40392835999    1245.55607291794    1244.82436807251    1243.29167141097    1243.28971893920    1243.28699631652    1243.29654745254    1243.28181288207    1243.27905732444    1243.28645837898    1243.71257719647    1243.69709776913    1243.70094018018    1243.27603995590    1243.28148520126    1243.29228786544    1243.28135179275    1243.29002633209    1243.27853203391    1243.27966280059    1243.28181455078    1243.28257205467    1243.28102411193    1243.28110096015    1243.28604120292    1243.29498853149    1243.29017835982    1243.63117780444    1244.75454597473    1244.87475854874    1244.85444866180    1243.66586928699    1243.28855356887    1243.29290265121    1243.28642544402    1243.28151813621    1243.27933345107    1243.27788431320    1243.27827953262    1243.28197922553    1243.28817099647    1243.29270504150    1243.29273797645    1243.28575576667    1243.28462499999    1243.27844420738    1243.27697311286    1243.69094991147    1243.21467713461    1243.20754122839    1243.22927829657    1243.21895867834    1243.69918364941    1243.27681941642    1243.27802703132    1243.27966280059    1243.28274770774    1243.28114487342    1243.28462499999    1243.28170476760    1243.28407608413    1243.28195726890    1243.28799534339    1243.28328564529    1243.28144128799    1243.27923464622    1243.27852105560    1243.70873478543    1243.27647908859    1243.70774673688    1243.69742711865    1243.27587528114    1243.27599604263    1243.69764668500    1243.63309417950    1243.61794410168    1243.57359169995    1243.57051777112    1243.60334293973    1243.58885156094    1243.59049830853    1243.63759528958    1243.66515086591    1243.69040099561    1243.69995213162    1243.21083472357    1243.21895867834    1243.21588474951    1243.21160320578    1243.21654344855    1243.64319423138    1243.63792463910    1243.22016629324    1243.27645713195    1243.28242933654    1243.29187068939    1243.29868822441    1243.27915612929    1243.29016738151    1243.51129457996    1243.56245353839    1243.56871117923    1243.21026771544    1243.48615423343    1243.29500881942    1243.29303272231    1243.29012346824    1243.28853161223    1243.29036499122    1243.29343892005    1243.29868655570    1243.22179494857    1243.63370281741    1243.22121406384    1243.71296626804    1244.66090092850    1244.67857601929    1244.67725862122    1244.64289648819    1243.20913791486    1243.58133624408    1243.55323175189    1243.51766200397    1243.29873046897    1243.29381218284    1243.29435012038    1243.29313152717    1243.29234108832    1243.28820226272    1243.28710443099    1243.28666529830    1243.28826813262    1243.28830106757    1243.28496365912    1243.28538083518    1243.28416224196    1243.28444767821    1243.28024298270    1243.27920004256    1243.27834373382    1243.27709220565    1243.29868822441    1243.29801854705    1243.27743253348    1243.27629078849    1243.29598755836    1243.29514222793    1243.29403341789    1243.29643766937    1243.27646644157    1243.29456037712    1243.27626883185    1243.28295462707    1243.28454648307    1243.28358039115    1243.29635915244    1243.48450748584    1243.52018701694    1243.55861112735    1243.55246326968    1243.22783302306    1243.22212429808    1243.21180467986    1243.29862068580    1243.29539306052    1243.29299978736    1243.29185804236    1243.29549186538    1243.29529425567    1243.49219230792    1243.51875983569    1243.59275369403    1243.65522031924    1244.66792705154    1244.79560488129    1244.89210429001    1245.01012120056    1245.07675958633    1245.18566449356    1245.18193186569    1245.06654975128    1244.90692501831    1244.74488505554    1243.64896267841    1243.49131404254    1243.28588583777    1243.28053939727    1243.28633594878    1243.29122129996    1243.29237402328    1243.29283511260    1243.50174344394    1243.59560805652    1243.22845975323    1244.64256713867    1243.21901840039    1243.22824018689    1244.67385534287    1244.67923471832    1244.65859548187    1243.70626949451    1243.64281482074    1243.44335407793    1243.29590904143    1243.28990390189    1243.28401952384    1243.27788264449    1243.29539472923    1243.29599853668    1243.29845767974    1243.27752036002    1243.28191168693    1243.29115543006    1243.43742578661    1243.57211445758    1243.60153634784    1243.65697685001    1244.63740732956    1244.71985449219    1244.77683195877    1244.73555348587    1243.45506890854    1243.59813306949    1243.55487849948    1243.29665556701    1243.28843280738    1243.28271310409    1243.29763430595    1243.29460429038    1243.29762332763    1243.29456037712    1243.29626201629    1243.27813514579    1243.28554550994    1243.28908052810    1243.29462457831    1243.49504667041    1243.60318309543    1244.64673889923    1244.76014491653    1244.88946949387    1245.00024071503    1245.07478348923    1245.04514203262    1244.93766430664    1244.82118436050    1243.44683517059    1243.43863340151    1243.28192266524    1243.28365890807    1243.65109861981    1243.61366255795    1243.65142796933    1243.63034960019    1243.65790517651    1243.27776355171    1243.29145351333    1243.27945254386    1243.28426104682    1243.28850965560    1243.29623839095    1243.52271202991    1243.60779398868    1243.64094850681    1243.57222424075    1243.28572116302    1243.29243058357    1243.28000312843    1243.66580956494    1243.57743411099    1243.50805114590    1243.69579705811    1243.43833883130    1243.70864168930    1243.52715341794    1243.61333320844    1243.60938101422    1243.60015922772    1243.61772453534    1243.43931019281    1243.70994240033    1243.27700604782    1243.27987138862    1243.28497630615    1243.28349423332    1243.71169893109    1243.65274536740    1243.62881263577    1243.61014949643    1243.56755362546    1243.57622649609    1243.58248413693    1243.57875150906    1243.45580963756    1243.52243274152    1243.43923237850    1243.44527045299    1243.44570958568    1243.55218398129    1243.62947133481    1243.44062759088    1243.62354304349    1243.58259392011    1243.56382099759    1243.59313310468    1243.61223537671    1243.61212559354    1243.63781485593    1243.44633631586    1243.70170866238    1243.45753419946    1243.22750147788    1243.22803941542    1243.22896159407    1243.27790626983    1243.27779648666    1243.22870909278    1243.22338460891    1243.21919089171    1243.45591942073    1243.21052899939    1243.20900301329    1243.20935431945    1243.20989225699    1243.22932554725    1243.20942018935    1243.21829066970    1243.22390058982    1243.22324189078    1243.22065100791    1243.63891268765    1243.63957138669    1243.60883209836    1243.61607778775    1243.64264531552    1243.69160861050    1243.27821366271    1243.28192433395    1243.28579967994    1243.28958719940    1243.28854425926    1243.28006899833    1243.70445324170    1243.64978122174    1243.61640713727    1243.59412115323    1243.62727567136    1243.70851521909    1243.28374673461    1243.29154133987    1243.29284775962    1243.29382482986    1243.29290265121    1243.29543864250    1243.29819420013    1243.29729397811    1243.29311123924    1243.29471407356    1243.29479092178    1243.28534956893    1243.27741224555    1243.69062056195    1243.27859790382    1243.28474576148    1243.28898339195    1243.29674506225    1243.27854134353    1243.28180190375    1243.29488805793    1243.56508833453    1243.65642793414    1243.45312478029    1243.28953063911    1243.27693850921    1243.29196949424    1243.29302341270    1243.29569114379    1243.27623589690    1243.29658038749    1243.29619614639    1243.29082774925    1243.29245254020    1243.29156329650    1243.28953230781    1243.28514098091    1243.28393336601    1243.28774284210    1243.28813806152    1243.28845643272    1243.28720490455    1243.28833567123    1243.29101438064    1243.27728981536    1243.29251674140    1243.61108748386    1244.63641928101];

Number_Of_Bins = 70;
Count_Array = zeros(1,Number_Of_Bins);
Bin_Array = zeros(1,Number_Of_Bins);

Number_Of_Data_Points = length(Data);
Minimum_Value = min(Data,[],'all');
Maximum_Value = max(Data,[],'all');

Range = Maximum_Value - Minimum_Value;
Bin_Interval = Range/Number_Of_Bins;


for Bin_Index = 1: +1: Number_Of_Bins
   
    Bin_Start_Edge = Minimum_Value + ((Bin_Index-1)*Bin_Interval);
    Bin_End_Edge = Minimum_Value + ((Bin_Index)*Bin_Interval);
    Bin_Array(1,Bin_Index) = (Bin_Start_Edge+Bin_Start_Edge)/2;
 
    for Data_Index = 1: +1: Number_Of_Data_Points
    Data_Value = Data(1,Data_Index);
    
    if((Data_Value >= Bin_Start_Edge) && (Data_Value <= Bin_End_Edge))  
    Count_Array(1,Bin_Index) = Count_Array(1,Bin_Index) + 1;
    end
    
    end
      
end

Probabilities = Count_Array./length(Data);
plot(Bin_Array,Probabilities)
title("Probability Graph");
xlabel("Data Value"); ylabel("Probabilities");
grid;

%Checking that the probabilities add to 1%
sum(Probabilities,'all')
```

### Extension: Bins and Occurrences Fundamentals

[image: Histogram Analysis]

**Using MATLAB version: R2019b**